# swift - substring from string

Tags: ios, swift, substring

I have some of url string like:

let url1 = "https://abc/help?user_info_id=5#help-article03"

let url2 = "https://cde?user_info_id=455&artical=4"

let url3 = "https://ghi/help?user_info_id=5"

Now i want to get user_info_id from these urls.

url1 return 5, url2 return 455 and url3 return 5

This is my code

```
func getID(string: String) -> String {
    let range = string.rangeOfString("user_info_id=")
    guard let endIndex = range?.endIndex else { return "" }
    let remain = string.substringFromIndex(endIndex)

    let num = "0123456789"
    var result = ""
    for c in remain.characters {
        if num.containsString(String(c)) {
            result.append(c)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Please tell me your idea. Thank you!

Comment: try regex for this

Comment: You also could use https://github.com/kylef/URITemplate.swift lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `(NS)URLComponents` and filter the query items:

```
let url1 = "https://cde?user_info_id=455&artical=4"
if let components = NSURLComponents(string: url1),
  let queryItems = components.queryItems,
  let userInfoId = queryItems.filter({$0.name == "user_info_id"}).first where userInfoId.value != nil {
  print(userInfoId.value!)
}
```