# Trimming Substrings from String Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: swift, string, swiftui, substring, trim

Let's say I have the following strings:

```
"Chest Stretch (left)"
"Chest Stretch (right)"
```

How can I use SwiftUI to output only:

```
"Chest Stretch"
```

I thought this may be a possible duplicate of [swift - substring from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686219/swift-substring-from-string).

However, I am seeking a way to do this inside `var body: some View` within an `if` conditional expression.

Comment: Could you explain why this is a SwiftUI question and why you need to do string manipulation inside a view? Please also add your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: For convenience - I could certainly handle this with a data structure inside my observed object or environment object and have the data ready by the time we're at the view. But, that gets into a larger design philosophy discussion. Even if its an antipattern to do this inside view, I am curious if it can be done. It's a huge convenience factor.

Comment: What are the criteria for trimming? Do you just want the first 13 characters? Delete anything in parentheses? Omit trailing words that aren't capitalized? Delete the last word?

Comment: @Caleb basically deleting the last parenthetical expression and removing the whitespace right before it.

Comment: So search from the right for the first open paren, and truncate the string up to that character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible way is Regular Expression

```
let string = "Chest Stretch (left)"
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s\\([^)]+\\)", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The found pattern will be replaced with an empty string.

The pattern is:

- One whitespace character `\\s`
- An opening parenthesis `\\(`
- One or more characters which are not a closing parentheses `[^)]+`
- and a closing parenthesis `\\)`

---

Or simpler if the delimiter character is always the opening parenthesis

```
let trimmedString = String(string.prefix(while: {$0 != "("}).dropLast())
```

Or

```
let trimmedString = string.components(separatedBy: " (").first!
```

Comment: This is perfect

Comment: `let trimmedString = String(string.prefix(while: {$0 != "("})).dropLast()` Initializing a new string before dropping the last element is pointless. It will result in a substring. You probably meant `String(string.prefix { $0 != "(" }.dropLast())` otherwise simply `string.prefix { $0 != "(" }.dropLast()` would suffice.